# Youtube keyless API to retrieve video information by id

Tags: json, api, youtube

I'm looking for a youtube API to retrieve information by id (like l3UPzd1ci1k) which:

- Does not require a sign up to get a 'Developer key'.
- Outputs title, date, and probably comment/description given a video ID which is visible in the URL.
- Preferably uses JSON to output the information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The YouTube API doesn't require authentication for read-only queries that don't rely on information about a specific user, so you can use the standard API, e.g. http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/3aICB2mUu2k?v=2&alt=json. See [the documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html) for details.